# Keyframes deleted but model still 'floats'

Tags: animation, armature, keyframes

I'm trying to redo my walking animation. I've deleted all the keyframes under the Dope Sheet/NLA Editor etc., but my model still 'floats' along when I hit play. Prior to removing everything I could find, there were no keyframes showing on the Timeline either. Even if I selected the Armature, the keyframes weren't showing. How do I get them to show? How can I stop it floating along?

Thanks

Comment: In the Dope sheet have you clicked the Ghost and the Life ring icons to show additional keyframe data? If the does not help I think you would need to uplaod the .blend for us to look at https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I hadn't, no. Looks like there were a couple of keyframes for the start and end. It's sorted now. Thank you. :D